# Why does Test-Path cmdlet incorrectly report false when I use an environment variable?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I'm on a Win 7 machine using Powershell 4.0

```
PS C:\> $psversiontable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                               
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                                                                                                 
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                 
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                             
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                     
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.18728                                                                                                                                                      
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                                                                                                
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

See command line exercise below. The dll exists. The environment variable exists and has the correct path. When I use the the environment variable with `Test-Path`, it incorrectly reports `$false`. When I use a string literal with `Test-Path`, it correctly reports `$true`

Why does `Test-Path` incorrectly report false when I use the environment variable?

```
PS C:\> dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Gemalto\NET Smartcard Framework SDK\v2.3.0\bin\SmartCard.Runtime.dll"

    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Gemalto\NET Smartcard Framework SDK\v2.3.0\bin

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                  
-a---         1/13/2012   6:57 PM     131072 SmartCard.Runtime.dll                                                                                                                                 

PS C:\> Write-Host $env:GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Gemalto\NET Smartcard Framework SDK\v2.3.0\bin\SmartCard.Runtime.dll"

PS C:\> Test-Path $env:GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL

False

PS C:\> Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Gemalto\NET Smartcard Framework SDK\v2.3.0\bin\SmartCard.Runtime.dll"
True
```

Comment: I'm not following. Where do you see Test-Path '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Gemalto\NET Smartcard Framework SDK\v2.3.0\bin\SmartCard.Runtime.dll"'? (i.e., the path with both single quotes and double-quotes?

Comment: Here `Test-Path $env:GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL`. You print value of `$env:GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL` and you can see: it include literal `"`.

Comment: You're right. Since the path name include spaces, I surrounded the path name with double quotes when I created the content of the environment variable. So, in my script, I loaded the content of the environment variable into a string and removed the double quotes and it works. I left the double quotes on the content of the environment variable in case some other non-PowerShell software uses it. I guess `test-path` doesn't require a quoted path when the path includes spaces? Please add your fix as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: "*I guess test-path doesn't require a quoted path when the path includes spaces?*" - it does if you type at the interactive prompt, but the quotes are not part of the path on the filesystem, the quotes are for PowerShell parser to treat the whole string as a single argument with spaces, instead of two, three or more. The PowerShell reader effectively gets rid of the quotes, and the path handed to Test-Path is a single text with spaces in it, but not with quotes in it. If you have the path in a variable, that is a single argument even if the path has spaces. CMD prompt interpretation can differ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you print `Write-Host $env:GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL`, then you can see that environment variable `GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL` includes literal `"` as part of its value. That is incorrect. You should remove them before passing to `Test-Path`: `$env:GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL.Trim('"')`, for example.

Note: although `"` is invalid character for file system path, it is not invalid character for PowerShell path, as it is not limited for file system only.

```
New-PSDrive -Name '"C' -PSProvider Variable -Root \
${Program Files (x86)\Gemalto\NET Smartcard Framework SDK\v2.3.0\bin\SmartCard.Runtime.dll"} = 'Value'
Test-Path $env:GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL
```

Comment: As powershell is suposed to gain more and more cross-platform awareness, please note that `"` is not an invalid character on UNIX-based FS. Try `touch '"' && ls -l '"' && rm '"'`. I'm not saying it's a good idea to name files like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not due to environment variables (they are just variables in a different drive- `Env:` versus `Variable:`), but with the contents of your environment variable.  If you are creating this variable in cmd, you should use the following syntax:

```
SET "GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL=C:\Program Files(x86)\.."
```

Arguments in PowerShell are a bit smarter than batch arguments and passing a variable counts as an argument in its entirety, regardless of its contents.

In your specific case, your variable has quote characters as part of the contents which doesn't make sense to `Test-Path`:

```
PS C:\> $Env:GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Gemalto\NET Smartcard Framework SDK\v2.3.0\bin\SmartCard.Runtime.dll"
```

You can fix this by fixing the declaration of the environment variable, or you can fix it in your code:

```
$GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL = $Env:GEMALTO_SMARTCARD_DLL -replace '^"' -replace '"$'
```

Comment: Just for clarity's sake: The environment variable was created manually using the Windows facility: Start->Edit environment variables for your account->New, etc etc.

Comment: @NovaSysEng An alternative to that even, would be using the `[Environment]` .net class and add the environment variable that way.