# File path with quotation mark issue of Powershell

Tags: powershell

I was trying to write a script to test the availability of the file path. One of the process is that user have to input the file path or just drag the file into the Powershell command prompt.

In this process,
User will input the file path like **C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe** and the string will become the value of **$filePath** variable which will be used as the parameter of the Test-Path command.

But sometime, user will just drag the file into the Powershell command prompt so that the string will have a pair of quotation mark included just like the picture 1.
("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe")
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwS7a.jpg)

Then you will see when I try to test the path using Test-Path command with that $filePath variable while the value(string) of the $filePath included a pair of **quotation mark**, the result will always be False even though the path is existing and valid.
But when I use the same Test-Path command **without using variable** (I mean just copy and paste the file path into the command), it works normally.

IT'S WEIRD!

I have tried typing the file path by keyboard into the variable instead of dragging the file into Powershell command prompt. (Without Quotation mark)
Then use the same method to test the filepath (using variable for the file path). It works fine.

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkY2J.jpg)

I don't get it. Aren't they the same thing?

when

`$filePath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"`

Below 2 commands SHOULD have the same result! WHY they are not?

```
Test-Path -Path $filePath
Test-Path -Path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
```

Comment: I think this behavior is normal. When a variable contains `"Something"` its like you would write  `'" Something"'` in your console

Comment: Not a full dupe, but very related to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49817534

Comment: File names/paths cannot contain the quote (`"`) character. Quotes are for command-line parsers to specify arguments (to indicate that an argument contains whitespace)--the quotes are not part of the argument.

Answer (score 3):

In case of drag and drop, it looks like if the path has no spaces it will return true .  If it has a space then PowerShell places quotes around it. In that case, PowerShell is literally seeing the path as `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"`

What you can do is use the `-replace` operator like this -

```
Test-Path -path ($filepath -replace '"', "") -PathType Leaf
```

**OR**

As suggested by @Josefz in the comments, you could also use `Trim()` method like -

```
Test-Path -path ($filepath.Trim('"')) -PathType Leaf
```

Not exactly an explanation to your problem, but you could use this as a workaround.

Comment: Try `$filePath.Trim('"')` instead of `-replace`

Comment: @JosefZ - That will also do, but any specific reason for the same?

Comment: "if the path has no spaces it will return true" - not quite. The problem is the `"` characters, not the spaces.

Comment: Yes the problem is `"` and it comes into picture when a user drags and drop a path to the PowerShell console and if the file path contains spaces(e.g. `C:\Program Files`) then the double quotes are automatically placed. The OP is talking about a similar issue when he drags and drops to the PoSh console. That's what I meant. Edited the answer to make more sense.

Comment: Correct--the quotes are added when using drag and drop because the assumption is that the filename will be used on the command line and will need to be parsed as a single argument. (The `"` characters are not part of the file's name.)

Comment: Great! thank you for the help. I used the Trim() method and it is good for me.

Answer (score 2):

If the user types a filename that contains embedded `"` characters, then `Test-Path` will return `$false`. Why? File names cannot contain the `"` character; the `"` character is used by parsers to indicate that an argument in a string contains whitespace. So this will of course return `$false`:

```
$filePath = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"'
Test-Path $filePath
```

The embedded `"` characters are not part of the file name; you need to omit them for the result to be `$true`.

Comment: Yes! When I use Read-Host cmdlet, it will literally save all I have inputted as a string included the quotation mark "". 
All I need to do is remove the quotation mark using Trim() method like @Vivek Kumar Singh said

Answer (score 0):

What version of powershell are you using? I get `true` for both commands

```
PS C:\Users> $filePath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
PS C:\Users> Test-Path -Path $filePath
True
PS C:\Users> Test-Path -Path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
True
PS C:\Users> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  48
```

**EDIT ----------**

Got it, the problem is that Read-Host will save the string literally, with the quotes. The simple solution is to remove the quotes

```
PS C:\Users> $filePath = Read-Host -Prompt "enter input"
enter input: "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
PS C:\Users> $filePath
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
PS C:\Users> Test-Path -Path $filePath
False
PS C:\Users> Test-Path -Path $filePath.replace("`"","")
True
```

Comment: His filepath variable contains `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"` and not `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe`. Its like you would write `test-path '"C:"'` this will also be false in powershell 5

Comment: @guiwhatsthat `test-path '"C:"'` is not necessary false.

Comment: @PetSerAl When I write the command like that `test-path '"C:"'` the result will be false. When will it be true? can you explain it?

Comment: @guiwhatsthat `New-PSDrive '"C' Variable \ | Out-Null; ${"} = 'Exist'; test-path '"C:"'`

Comment: Yes. It's because of Read-Host! Thank you, bro!